# How to grep from a single line

Tags: bash, api, grep

I'm using a weather API that outputs all data in a single line. How do I use grep to get the values for "summary" and "apparentTemperature"? My command of regular expressions is basically nonexistent, but I'm ready to learn.

```
{"latitude":59.433335,"longitude":24.750486,"timezone":"Europe/Tallinn","offset":2,"currently":{"time":1485880052,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":0.76,"apparentTemperature":-3.34,"dewPoint":-0.13,"humidity":0.94,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":262,"visibility":9.99,"cloudCover":0.11,"pressure":1017.72,"ozone":282.98}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I use grep to get the values for "summary" and "apparentTemperature"?

You use `grep`'s `-o` flag, which makes it output only the matched part.

Since you don't know much about regex, I suggest you instead learn to use a JSON parser, which would be more appropriate for this task.

For example with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), the following command would extract the current summary :

```
<whatever is your JSON source> | jq '.currently.summary'
```

Comment: Okay, jq works fine. This is a simple bash script though, one that I might want to share with people and it would be rather inconvenient for them to download a package just to run a script.

Would you mind showing me how to do it with regex?

Comment: If they just want to execute the script, then I guess a regex will indeed be more easily portable (although this is debatable). If they need to be able to maintain it, then no matter how much I love regexs, I'd recommend `jq` :) edit : I previously mentioned I'd add a regex-based solution anyway, but the one provided by Fred looks nice enough

Comment: @user1901162 `jq`'s homepage mentions that it is a portable single executable (of 2.9Mo I think), so you could make a tar or zip of your script + jq to distribute it and provide instruction on how to dezip + execute the script. Plus that way you don't have to worry about jq's version compatibility since you package your script with a tested version of jq.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your single-line data is contained in a variable called `DATA_LINE`.

If you are certain the field is only present once in the whole line, you could do something like this in Bash:

```
if
  [[ "$DATA_LINE" =~ \"summary\":\"([^\"]*)\" ]]
then
  summary="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "Summary field is : $summary"
else
  echo "Summary field not found"
fi
```

You would have to do that once for each field, unless you build a more complex matching expression that assumes fields are in a specific order.

As a note, the matching expression `\"summary\":\"([^\"]*)\"` finds the first occurrence in the data of a substring consisting of :

- "summary":" (double quotes included), followed by
- ([^\"]*) a sub-expression formed of a sequence of zero or more characters other than a double quote : this is in parentheses to make it available later as an element in the BASH_REMATCH array, because this is the value you want to extract
- and finally a final quote ; this is not absolutely necessary, but protects from reading from a truncated data line.

For `apparentTemperature` the code will be a bit different because the field does not have the same format.

```
if
  [[ "$DATA_LINE" =~ \"apparentTemperature\":([^,]*), ]]
then
  apparentTemperature="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "Apparent temperature field is : $apparentTemperature"
else
  echo "Apparent temperature field  not found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Having a bit of trouble though. I can get the summary to show, but not apparentTemperature. I've done it twice for both summary and apparentTemperature, but the latter doesn't work.

Comment: @user1901162 Please see end of updated answer.  You should study how the two regex patterns differ and compare how the fields are delimited in your data to understand the changes.

Comment: @user1901162  By the way, the code I suggested has no dependency except for Bash (this code is not POSIX-compliant).  No external command is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easily understood if your skills are limited - like mine! Assuming your string is in a variable called `$LINE`:

```
summary=$(sed -e 's/.*summary":"//'  -e 's/".*//' <<< $LINE)
```

Then check:

```
echo $summary
Clear
```

That executes (`-e`) 2 `sed` commands. The first one substitutes everything up to `summary":"` with nothing and the second substitutes the first remaining double quote and everything that follows with nothing.

Extract apparent temperature:

```
appTemp=$(sed -e 's/.*apparentTemperature"://'  -e 's/,.*//' <<< $LINE)
```

Then check:

```
echo $appTemp
-3.34
```

Answer (score -1):

As Aaron mentioned a json parser like `jq` is the right tool for this, but since the question was about `grep`, let's see one way to do it.

Assuming your API return value is in `$json`:

```
json='{"latitude":59.433335,"longitude":24.750486,"timezone":"Europe/Tallinn","offset":2,"currently":{"time":1485880052,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":0.76,"apparentTemperature":-3.34,"dewPoint":-0.13,"humidity":0.94,"windSpeed":3.99,"windBearing":262,"visibility":9.99,"cloudCover":0.11,"pressure":1017.72,"ozone":282.98}}'
```

The patterns you see in the parenthesis are lookbehind and lookahead assertions for context matching. They can be used with the `-P` Perl regex option and will not be captured in the output.

```
summary=$(<<< "$json" grep -oP '(?<="summary":").*?(?=",)')
apparentTemperature=$(<<< "$json" grep -oP '(?<="apparentTemperature":).*?(?=,)')
```